# ASP.NET Assign values to int array in .ascx file

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I want to use a Telerik control called RadDataPager and subsequently modify it's default values for page sizes. So, there is something called a RadDataPagerPageSizeField that contains an attribute, PageSizes, that contains an int[] of possible values.

I have not been able to either reach this field in the code behind, or assign a value to it in the .ascx.

When I do PageSizes = "9,18,27,45", I get an exception saying I can't assign Object[] to an int[] field.

edit: This is my RadDataPager (there is nothing on it in the code behind, at present)

```
<telerik:RadDataPager runat="server" ID="ProductsListDataPager" PagedControlID="ProductsListView">
        <Fields>
            <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="FirstPrev" />
            <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="Numeric" />
            <telerik:RadDataPagerPageSizeField PageSizes="9, 18, 27, 45" />
            <telerik:RadDataPagerButtonField FieldType="NextLast" />
        </Fields>
    </telerik:RadDataPager>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try assigning the PageSizes as follows:

```
   List<int> data = new List<int>() { 9, 18, 27, 45 };
   PageSizes = data.ToArray();
```

Comment: Pardon my inexperience, but can I just define and refer to this variable in the .ascx then?

Comment: Did you try setting it as: **<telerik:RadDataPagerPageSizeField PageSizes="9, 18, 27, 45" />**  that seemed to work for me.

Comment: Yes, that's when I get an exception, saying I can't assign Object[] to int[]. It really puzzles me that this works for you.

Comment: For clarity: I try to do this within the <Fields> tag och the RadDataPager.

Comment: Do you want to share some of your code?  maybe the error is coming from somewhere else?

Comment: After further testing, this does not seem to work properly...  according to http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/datapager-elements.html your code should work.  You might want to open a ticket with Telerik.